# Telerik Grid - binding to stored procedure not working in Razor Pages

Tags: stored-procedures, razor, grid, telerik, controls

I am new to Telerik Grid and working on Telerik Grid to bind the SQL Server stored procedure, the grid is getting displayed and it is empty  (no data).

When I compile the code I get the error for Json (the name does not exist in the current context). Also, the Grid is getting displayed but there is no data.

Please assist

This is my code:

`TestGrid.cshtml`:

```
@page
@model CountyBillingSystemProj.Pages.TEMP.TestGridModel

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CountyBillingSystemProj.CommonControls.UserFields>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.ID);
            columns.Bound(c => c.PersonRequested);
            columns.Bound(c => c.UserID);
            columns.Bound(c => c.LoginID);
            columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName).Width(50);
            columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName).Width(50);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Email).Width(150);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Telephone).Width(50);

        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "height: 550px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("RetrieveUserRecord","Home"))
            .PageSize(20)
        )
)
```

`Properties.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CountyBillingSystemProj.CommonControls
{
    public class Properties
    {
    }  // end of Properties  
 
    [Serializable()]
    public class UserFields
    {
        public int ID { get; set; } = 0;// The ID is the Primary Key.
        public string PersonRequested { get; set; } = "";
        public string UserID { get; set; } = "";
        public string LoginID { get; set; } = "";
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
        public string LastName { get; set; } = "";
        public string Telephone { get; set; } = "";
        public string Email { get; set; } = "";        
    }    // end of UserFields   
}    // end of namespace
```

`StoredProcedure.cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using CountyBillingSystemProj.CommonControls;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;

public IActionResult RetrieveUserRecord([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{           
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(GetSQLServerConnectionString());

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_GetAllUsers";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sqlConn.Open();
            sd.Fill(dt);
            sqlConn.Close();

            List<UserFields> userFields = new List<UserFields>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                UserFields uf = new UserFields();
                uf.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["EmpID"]);
                uf.PersonRequested = dr["PersonRequested"].ToString();
                uf.UserID = dr["UserID"].ToString();
                uf.LoginID = dr["LoginID"].ToString();
                uf.FirstName = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
                uf.LastName = dr["LastName"].ToString();
                uf.Telephone = dr["Telephone"].ToString();
                uf.Email = dr["Email"].ToString();

                userFields.Add(uf);
            } // end of for

            DataSourceResult response = userFields.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}   // end of RetrieveUserRecord()
```

Thanks,

Muder

The grid should display the data from the stored procedure.

Comment: If you add a breakpoint in your StoredProcedure.cs on the return line, are you returning data? If you run the procedure in your local Sql Server are you getting data? Are you certain that the column names you are referencing exist in your query? You likely need to include some of the information from your query here as well other than just the name of the SP. I would start by including the select list only if you do not wish to obfuscate DB structure.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, Yes I am getting the data from the Stored Procedure, and the field names are correct. The stored Procedure is working fine.

Comment: When you execute the Sp and attempt to fill the datatable, does the datatable ever have anything in it? If instead of filling the datatable you just read over the results do you get rows back at all? instead of sd.fill(dt) try `using rs = cmd.executeReader() while rs.read() dim d = 1 End while End Using` and break on dim d=1. Confirm that oyu are even seeing data come back from your SP at all in the application. We can worry about getting it into the grid once we know we have data.

Comment: Also, if you are getting an error/exception, please post that in its entirety as well as exactly which line it is being thrown on.

Comment: The Telerik Grid is working now, nothing was wrong with the stored Procedure, there was a Conflict between "using Kendo.Mvc;" and "using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;" For the Razor Pages you only need "using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;"  reference not the "using Kendo.Mvc;" . Now, everything is working fine. Thanks for your help. !!!